# Phaser 3: Check if draggable Object is over interactive area of a Sprite

Tags: javascript, event-handling, drag, phaser-framework

What I want to achieve is to be able to drag a Sprite, and when it moves over the interactive area of another Sprite, it emits particles.

However the Pointermove event doesn't get called if I am dragging a different sprite (likely since my pointer is over the draggable sprite, not the interactive sprite.) I tried adding an If-Condition to my drag event instead, which tests if my draggable object is over the interactive Sprite, which sort of works, but it reacts over any area of the sprite, as opposed to exclusively the interactive area. This is important because my Sprite's interactive area uses `pixel perfect`.

Is there any way to achieve the result I am looking for?

My try with Pointermove:

```
gameState.chara.setInteractive({cursor: "pointer", pixelPerfect: true});

gameState.chara.on('pointermove', function(activePointer){ 
    if (activePointer.isDown && gameState.clean_cursor) {
        switch(gameState.clean_cursor.frame.name.split('_')[0]){
        case "sponge":
            gameState.bubble.emitParticle(1, activePointer.x, activePointer.y);
            break;
        case "showerhead":
            gameState.splash.emitParticle(1, activePointer.x-50, activePointer.y+50);
            break;
        }
    }
});

this.input.on('drag', (activePointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) => {
    switch(gameObject.frame.name.split('_')[0]){
    case "sponge":
        gameState.clean_cursor.play('sponge_cursor', true);
        break;
    case "showerhead":
        gameState.clean_cursor.play('shower_cursor', true);
        break;
    }
        
    gameObject.x = dragX;
    gameObject.y = dragY;
});
    
this.input.on('dragend', function(pointer, gameObject) {
    gameObject.destroy();
    gameState.clean_cursor = false;
});
```

(Pointermove Event stops reacting once I drag the other sprite)

My attempt with Drag only:

```
gameState.chara.setInteractive({cursor: "pointer", pixelPerfect: true});

this.input.on('drag', (activePointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) => {
    if(gameState.chara.getBounds().contains(dragX, dragY)) {
        switch(gameState.clean_cursor.frame.name.split('_')[0]){
        case "sponge":
            gameState.bubble.emitParticle(1, activePointer.x, activePointer.y);
            break;
        case "showerhead":
            gameState.splash.emitParticle(1, activePointer.x-50, activePointer.y+50);
            break;
        }
    }

    switch(gameObject.frame.name.split('_')[0]){
    case "sponge":
        gameState.clean_cursor.play('sponge_cursor', true);
        break;
    case "showerhead":
        gameState.clean_cursor.play('shower_cursor', true);
        break;
    }
        
    gameObject.x = dragX;
    gameObject.y = dragY;
});
    
this.input.on('dragend', function(pointer, gameObject) {
    gameObject.destroy();
});
```

(Works, but over entire sprite, as opposed to the Pixel Perfect interactive Area only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the solution how to dragg the button/image https://stackoverflow.com/a/71310078/1679286

the solution, for this question should be easy.

- Just check if the sprite overlaps with the boundaries. (is not pixelperfect, because it matches boxes) [here the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Intersects.html#.RectangleToRectangle)

*if you need pixel-perfect, this would be more difficult.*

**Here the code, for the "simple" solution:**
*(the code needs some tweaking)*

```js
let Example = {
    preload () {
        this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
            this.load.atlas('flares', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/particles/flares.png', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/particles/flares.json');
    },
    create () {
    
        this._particles = this.add.particles('flares');

        this._emitter = this._particles.createEmitter({
            frame: 'blue',
            lifespan: 2000,
            speed: { min: 50, max: 400 },
            angle: 330,
            gravityY: 300,
            scale: { start: 0.4, end: 0 },
            quantity: 2,
            blendMode: 'ADD',
            on: false
        });
        
        let buttonPos = { x:20, y:20};
        let buttonPlaceholder = this.add.image(buttonPos.x, buttonPos.y, 'brawler', ).setOrigin(0.5);
        let button = this.add.image(buttonPos.x, buttonPos.y, 'brawler', ).setOrigin(0.5);
        
        let interact = this.add.image(200, 100, 'brawler', 3).setOrigin(0.5);
        
        interact.setDepth(-1); 

        button.setInteractive({ useHandCursor: true });
        this.input.setDraggable(button);
        
        this.input.on('drag', function(pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) {
            gameObject.x = dragX;
            gameObject.y = dragY;
            if(Phaser.Geom.Intersects.RectangleToRectangle(gameObject.getBounds(), interact.getBounds() )){
                this._emitter.start()
                this._particles.x = interact.x;
                this._particles.y = interact.y;
            } else {
              if (this._emitter.active){
                   this._emitter.stop();
              }
            }
        }, this);
        
        this.input.on('dragend', function(pointer, gameObject) {
            gameObject.x = buttonPos.x;
            gameObject.y = buttonPos.y;
          this._emitter.stop();
        }, this);
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: [ Example ]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **Extra info, to improve:** You could check overlap with [CircleToCircle](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Intersects.html#.CircleToCircle), and keeping the radius abit smaller. *(Or other intersection functions, that fit your needs better https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Intersects.html)*

**A pixel perfect version, could be done like this:**
*(just found this property `this.input.topOnly`, [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html#topOnly))*
If set to `false` this property allows the input events to be passed to other object, that are under the top most object.

```js
let Example = {
    preload () {
        this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
            this.load.atlas('flares', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/particles/flares.png', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/particles/flares.json');
    },
    create () {
    
        this.input.topOnly = false;

        let isDragging = false;
        
        this._particles = this.add.particles('flares');

        this._emitter = this._particles.createEmitter({
            frame: 'blue',
            lifespan: 2000,
            speed: { min: 400, max: 600 },
            angle: 330,
            gravityY: 300,
            scale: { start: 0.4, end: 0 },
            quantity: 2,
            blendMode: 'ADD',
            on: false
        });
        
        let buttonPos = { x:20, y:20};
        let buttonPlaceholder = this.add.image(buttonPos.x, buttonPos.y, 'brawler', )
             .setOrigin(0.5);
             
        let button = this.add.image(buttonPos.x, buttonPos.y, 'brawler', )
             .setOrigin(0.5);
        
        let interact = this.add.image(200, 100, 'brawler', 3)
             .setOrigin(0.5);

        interact
         .setInteractive(this.input.makePixelPerfect());

        interact.on('pointerover', function(pointer){
            if(isDragging){
                this._particles.x = interact.x;
                this._particles.y = interact.y;
                this._emitter.start();
            }
        }, this);
        
        interact.on('pointerout', function(pointer){
            this._emitter.stop();
        }, this);
        
        interact.setDepth(-1); 

        button.setInteractive({ useHandCursor: true });

        this.input.setDraggable(button);
        
        this.input.on('drag', function(pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) {
            isDragging = true;
            gameObject.x = dragX;
            gameObject.y = dragY;

        }, this);
        
        this.input.on('dragend', function(pointer, gameObject) {
            gameObject.x = buttonPos.x;
            gameObject.y = buttonPos.y;
            this._emitter.stop();
            isDragging = false;
        }, this);
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: [ Example ]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sadly the pixel perfect (or something similar) is necessary as otherwise there is a large transparent area that the particles spawn on, which they shouldn't. Although I have to admit, after finding the pixel perfect option, I didn't get to try your alternative to ignore transparent areas yet. I might just be able to implement that in here somehow.

Comment: @alex, I found a helpful property `topOnly` this make the pixelPerfect version easy. I updated the answer. Hope this helps.